# Determine amplitude and period of an added cosine

Tags: harmonic-functions

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmER3.png)

$g(t)=2\cos(\frac{\pi}{3}t)$     (dashed curve)

$f(t)=g(t) + Acos(\omega t)$ (drawn-through curve)

Obviously $A = 1$. But what is the value of $\omega$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over the interval $(0,6)$, your perturbed function $f$ oscillates three times around the base function $g$. That means that the perturbation must have three times the frequency of $g$ that is it must have $\omega=\pi$.